# How to create a group which is allowed to use the adduser command?

Tags: user-management

Does anyone know the commands for each step listed below?

1. Create a new sudoers group called `privilege1` allowing the use of the `adduser` command and nothing more. The sudoers configuration file is located at `/etc/sudoers`
2. Now create a new user called `user1` with the `adduser` command.
3. Then add user `user1` to the sudoers `privilege1` group to the `/etc/sudoers` file.
4. The final step is to test if that user `user1` can now use the `adduser` command.

Answer (score 2):

Allowing users to use `adduser` is no good since you'll also be able to assign random groups to this user. In Ubuntu, the group `admin` allows users to run commands as root. So, I suggest you adding the user to the `admin` group anyway since the other way requires just one step more to become root.

These *insecure* steps would allow you to become root:

```
you@host:~$ sudo adduser --ingroup admin user1
..
you@host:~$ su - user1
..
user1@host:~$ id -Gn
admin
user1@host:~$ sudo id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

Oops! You've just granted root access to an account where you wanted to limit the user on creating accounts only! Of course you can limit the command arguments, but user management should be considered an administrative task which should only be performable by `root`. Therefore, just add an user to the `admin` group if you want to allow the user to use `sudo` for executing commands as root:

```
sudo usermod -a -G admin name-of-existing-user
```